# "unable to get setup.ini" error during Cygwin installation

Tags: installation, cygwin

While installing `cygwin` I'm getting the following error

```
unable to get setup.ini
```

What is the reason?

I'm newly studying Unix. So Please guide me in this.

Comment: How you try to install `cygwin` and which Linix?

Comment: @KirilKirov: There is no Linux involved; Cygwin is a Unix-like environment for Windows.

Answer (score 26):

I had to switch from `setup.exe` to [setup-x86.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe) or [setup-x86_64.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe).

Comment: This worked for me too. Just went to cygwin.com and downloaded `setup-x86_64.exe` and it ran perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Cygwin recently changed the formatting of their mirror's folder structure to support both x86 and x64. Because of this `setup.exe` downloaded before this change no longer work due to them looking for the ini at `ftp.someMirrorName.com\cygwin` where the new location is `ftp.someMirrorName.com\cygwin\x86`

Comment: And here are the direct links for [setup-x86.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe) and [setup-x86_64.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) as of 2013-10-23.

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need go to [http://www.cygwin.com/] to download the latest setup.exe file.
actually, the error msg tells you that it can not find the setup.ini file, yes, the setup file changed the location.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same problem, when I selected "Direct connection to internet", then I did change it to "Use Internet Explorer Proxy Settings" and it worked so good... try and let me know..

Comment: Same here. Probably attributed to my being behind a corporate firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Try -X on the command line to setup.exe, worked for me.

The "Use Internet Explorer Proxy Settings" did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem when running `setup.exe` from a network drive.  When I copied `setup.exe` to my local drive, it ran correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `setup.exe` installer lets you select one of several dozen download locations (mirrors).  The `setup.ini` file is downloaded from the mirror you select.  If that fails, the first thing I'd try is to pick a different mirror.

It's also possible that you need to change the proxy settings (direct connection vs. IE proxy settings), as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL that follows that message ? Is there any ?

Doing a quick search on google I found that broken URLs causes that message.

See, for instance: http://prc-tools.sourceforge.net/install/cygwin.html

> If you get the error message Unable to get setup.ini from http://prc-tools[...], check the URL you added and add it again if necessary. Most people who have encountered this message have eventually found that it was caused by a mere typo, such as the addition of a trailing space to the URL.)

Try to download the URL directly in a browser. If you get 404 error, then you found the problem, and you should pickup another mirror download site on cygwin.

Also, I would really recommend installing Ubuntu sideways with Windows, if you're going to really study *nix systems.